# How to use Ruby on Rails Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to learn ruby on rails and i'm following the guide on "http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles".
i'm currently stuck with this.

> "Ensure you have a firm grasp of the params method, as you'll use it
>   fairly regularly.
>
> Let's consider an example URL:
>   http://www.example.com/?username=dhh&email=dhh@email.com.

In this URL

```
params[:username]
```

would equal "dhh" and

```
params[:email]
```

would equal "dhh@email.com".

i'm having some trouble understanding what the params are and how the guide wants me to use them.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: The params is a hash (with indifferent access), the username and email are keys for the hash.

Comment: I would say read a basic tutorial but it seems that is where you are already sruck.

Answer (score 0):

Eh.. I think your question is valid enough for someone starting out with Rails - though please note that you should format your question with code blocks and quotes.

The `params` hash in Rails exists to pass data between a user request (that could either be in a browser or an API request) and the Rails backend.

In the example you gave, the parameters are name and email, any data passed via the URL after the question mark (?) will be sent in params.  The need for that data depends on the particular action, and you'll "handle" that request in a controller.

2 samples of params:

1. You run a bookstore website and give a user a search form to find a book.  That form might contain an author, a title, a series name.  The user knows the same of the series is "Divergent".  But they can't remember the author and they want to see all the books in the series.

Your rails params will look like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"24hb1lZ93NnOHOXmSB5STy7UYPmfH/Xx7dho5y/
MHeQhXqWUGNv58WexwoJNqYubsSQqj+5A==", "author"=>"","series_name"=>"divergent", 
"title"=>"", "commit"=>"Search", "controller"=>"books", "action"=>"search"}
```

So in your books_controller.rb you'll have an action called search.  And that So ok, your user has requested a search term, now you need to perform the search and return the list of books to him.

So your action might look something like

```
def search
  # In this case your are offering 3 different filters, so you might have 3 different searches that you flatten to a single results array.
  authors = Book.where(author: params[:author])
  series = Book.where(series_name: params[:series])
  title = Book.where(title: params[:title])
  @books = [authors,series,title].flatten
end
```

Now you'll have to display your results, in the app/views/books/search.html.erb -- which you'll continue to understand as you progress with the edgeguides tutorials.

2. Next, example.  Lets say you have a shipping cart and ecommerce site.  A user is browsing through the womens clothing section, looking at scarves.   Lets say she only wants to find purple scarves and you give users a set of color option filters.  She clicks on the purple button, and your params might look like

   ```
   {"dept"=>"scarves", "color"=>"purple", "controller"=>"products", "action"=>"index"}
   ```

The params in this case are

- color
- controller
- action
- dept

This means your page is responding to the Products controller and the action called 'index".  Now in that action, you can create filters from the dept of scarves and the color purple to give the user just what they need.

If at any time you want or need to see the the params hash so you'll know better how to deal with it, you can view it directly in your browser by using

```
raise params.inspect
```

You can use that in a controller or in a view